# Dockerfile RUN command won't substitute environment variables?

Tags: bash, docker, environment-variables

My Dockerfile has:

```
ENV PROXY_HOST=sub.proxy.domain.com
ENV PROXY_PORT=8080
RUN sed -i 's/# https.proxyHost=/https.proxyHost=$PROXY_HOST/g' /opt/coldfusion/jre/conf/net.properties
```

But when I check `/opt/coldfusion/jre/conf/net.properties`, the line just reads:

```
https.proxyHost=$PROXY_HOST
```

For some reason it is not doing the variable substitution. I also tried using `${PROXY_HOST}` syntax. It just seems to literally interpret the variable name. I also tried to use `ARG` feature for Docker and the same syntax for the RUN command variables, and that did not work.

When I read the documentation and other StackOverflow answers, I feel like I am following the correct steps.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It's not a Docker-specific problem -- you'd have the same issue running the same sed command on a normal shell command line. Single-quotes _always_ suppress parameter expansion; if you want the variable to be substituted, use double quotes.

Comment: I just found this as well, thank you @CharlesDuffy